# How do I select a p without a span child

Tags: css

I'm trying

```
  p:not(> span)
    margin-top 0
    margin-bottom 0
    line-height 1.2
  p
    margin-top 0
    margin-bottom 0
    span
      line-height 1.2
```

and

```
  p:not(span)
    margin-top 0
    margin-bottom 0
    line-height 1.2
  p
    margin-top 0
    margin-bottom 0
    span
      line-height 1.2
```

but it seems `p` always has a line-height of 1.2, even if it has a child span.

```
<p style="text-align:center"><u>Lunch</u></p>
<p><span style="font-size:0.75em">Spaghetti and Meatballs</span></p>
```

The 1st `p` should have a line-heigh of 1.2 and the 2nd `p` should have a line-height of 0.

Comment: have you tried to set line height to the span itself ?? from your HTML sample, it will do. or the other way round https://jsfiddle.net/h8wgpuqp/

Comment: You **can't** style an element based on its children, but you **can** style a child based on its parent

Answer (score 0):

In css there is not any parent selecter. That is you you can't select a paragraph that is parent of a span. It's because of the fact that css is evaluated [right to left](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3958829/3429430). So if you really want to select only those `p` which are parent of `span` you need js/jquery. I know with jquery you can do:

```
$("p:not(:has(>span))")
```

Comment: @Justin808 If that's editable then just add a class to `p` in html and add `p.myClass {line-height: 0}` in css.

Comment: `p:nth-of-type(2)` seems to apply to the `p` with a `u` in it. I need it to apply only if there is a `span` in it.

Comment: @Justin808 `p:nth-of-type(2)` has nothing to do with `u` being in it or not. It simply apply to `nth` occurrence of `p`. In my example it applies to 2nd occurrence of p in whole html code. You need jquery/javscript to apply it to `p` that has `span`.

Comment: ahh, ok. sorry. Those where just examples, not the actual data. There could be many `p` tags. I need to target all `p`s without a `span`.